# Youtube embedded variables and parameters

Tags: visualforce, parameters

I can embed youtube videos in my visualforce pages like this

```
<apex:iframe width="750" height="422" 
   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1UCp5HtiyfA?rel=0" frameborder="1" />
```

but I can't figure out how to use the following additional variables because of all the & symbols.

```
?modestbranding=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&vq=large&controls=0
```

Comment: user19212, are they an issue because of visualforce or not ? Keep in mind that this forum is dedicated to questions in relation to salesforce.

Comment: This question is on topic.  Apex rips out the & symbols that youtube url's use.  I've tried using &amp; but they don't seem to be working correctly.  I'm trying to find out if there's a different way to add these parameters.

Comment: I've reopend the question. I think you have to use URLENCODE , see explained here: https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_security_tips_scontrols.htm

Comment: Here's what I've tried, but the extra parameters don't get applied.  Does anyone have a functioning example they could post?  https://www.youtube.com/embed/1UCp5HtiyfA?modestbranding=0&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;vq=hd720

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are documented right here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters